# Visual Studio Code и NodeJS жрут много ОЗУ

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

1)Visual Studio Code при старте хавает ~600 мб. К слову ~ столько же хавает полноценная IDE Visual Studio 2019.

Да стоят плагины, но имхо ничего там сверхъестественного нету:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2)Собираю небольшое Angular приложение с дефолтными настройками командой `ng Serve` и после этого появляется процесс NoneJS  который сжирает ~600 мб+ со временем он может разрастаться при долгом дебаге. Куда ему столько?
К слову, приложение на .Net Core жрет всего 40 мб.

Это можно как-нибудь пофиксить?

P.S Если имеет смысл разбить на 2 вопроса, то напишите в комментах.

Comment: У меня nodeejs используется для gulp. Так вот когда gulp работает в режиме watch, он у меня жрёт 2 гига.... 2 гига!!!! Что за бред

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev у меня подозрение, что нода все содержимое папки Node_modules в память грузит...

Comment: VS Code написан на Electron'e. Electon - это Хром... будет жрать столько, сколько дадут) Вот сейчас открыл свой диспетчер - у меня VS Code потребляет 1253 Мб... Из них 584, плагин `php CLI`. Что касается Angular - то все вопросы к нему... может действительно, он смотрит за `node_modules`

Comment: ... удалил `php CLI` и др. связанные с php плагины - VS Code стал потреблять 225 Мб)